# Invalid "IS NOT NULL" part of T-SQL statement

Tags: t-sql

What is wrong with this statement??

```
SELECT ID, datediff("mi", Start, End) as Total 
FROM TimeTable
WHERE Total is not null
```

I get an error "Invalid column name"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reference the expression, not the alias.

```
SELECT ID, datediff("mi", Start, [End]) as Total 
FROM TimeTable
WHERE datediff("mi", Start, [End])  is not null
```

EDIT, updated to prevent syntax error for usage of END

Comment: The select clause is processed, logically, prior to the where clause. The aliases are not available until after the select clause is processed. (Almost?) all clauses, except ORDER BY are processed prior to the select clause. Order by can use aliases because it is processed after the select clause.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use reserved words like "End" as table or column names!  Use something like TaskStart/TaskEnd or JobStart/JobEnd or StartDate/EndDate, you'll thanks me everytime you don't have to go back and add [] around your table/column names....

Comment: @Nick, thanks for the down vote! by following my answer `Don't use reserved words like "End" as table or column names` the OP's error `Invalid column name` would be solved.  Hardly worthy of a down vote, what in my answer is technically wrong? see: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down

Comment: @KM sorry, re-reading the whole thread your answer makes perfect sense. If I could retract the down-vote I would :( I was probably hacked off with SQL at the time.